# How can I reconstruct original matrix from SVD components with following shapes?

Tags: numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray, svd

I am trying to reconstruct the following matrix of shape (256 x 256 x 2) with SVD components as

```
U.shape = (256, 256, 256)
s.shape = (256, 2)
vh.shape = (256, 2, 2)
```

I have already tried methods from documentation of numpy and scipy to reconstruct the original matrix but failed multiple times, I think it maybe 3D matrix has a different way of reconstruction.
I am using **numpy.linalg.svd** for decompostion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **np.linalg.svd**'s documentation:

> "... If `a` has more than two dimensions, then broadcasting rules apply, as explained in :ref:`routines.linalg-broadcasting`. This means that SVD is
> working in "stacked" mode: it iterates over all indices of the first
> `a.ndim - 2` dimensions and for each combination SVD is applied to the
> last two indices."

This means that you only need to handle the `s` matrix (or tensor in general case) to obtain the right tensor. More precisely, what you need to do is pad `s` appropriately and then take only the first 2 columns (or generally, the number of rows of `vh` which should be equal to the number of columns of the returned `s`).

Here is a working code with example for your case:

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.random.randn(256, 256, 2) # Your matrix of dim 256 x 256 x2
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(mat) # Get the decomposition
# Pad the singular values' arrays, obtain diagonal matrix and take only first 2 columns:
s_rep = np.apply_along_axis(lambda _s: np.diag(np.pad(_s, (0, u.shape[1]-_s.shape[0])))[:, :_s.shape[0]], 1, s)
mat_reconstructed = u @ s_rep @ vh
```

`mat_reconstructed` equals to `mat` up to precision error.

Comment: Thankyou Sir, This was really helpful and worked as expected.

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: Hi, my original matrix is 30*2*50 and I am getting error. What code should I change?

Comment: @Agile_Eagle Hey, easiest way using this code would be to apply ```mat.transpose((0,2,1))``` so that dimension 2 is smaller or equal to dimension 1. The code should run well so that you only need to apply ```mat_reconstructed.transpose((0,2,1))``` once again to re-arrange the dimensions appropriately.